# Specific nouns in short answers

Tags: grammar, word-choice, word-usage, past-tense, questions

While analyzing a student's written essay, I came across a short answer written in the past progressive. It included an echoed name instead of a pronoun.

**Student's answer:** 
Was Sarah happy? Yes, Sarah was.

Is it possible to use a specific name in a short answer, or is a pronoun to be used?

Comment: To me, this sort of answer would suggest that while Sarah may have been happy, there were other relevant people who were not.

Comment: 'Is a pronoun to be used?' doesn't specify any constraints involved; it [wrongly] implies that there is a definitive answer here. The answer given is certainly grammatical. But, as linguisticturn implies, it is not in the usual style one would consider idiomatic for an unmarked response (because  repeating a noun instead of substituting the relevant pronoun without a good reason is clumsy). If one is marking to single out Sarah in contrast to others present, or for some other reason, the sentence actually becomes the correct choice.  Context is, as almost always, crucial.

Comment: In a spoken answer, you can achieve a similar implication by saying "she" with extra emphasis.

Comment: What do you think a "pronoun" is, anyway?

Answer (score 1):

Perfectly possible, elegant and euphonious. The repetition of her name adds emphasis.

> Euphony :
>
> 1 : pleasing or sweet sound; especially : the acoustic effect produced by words so formed or combined as to please the ear
> 2 : a harmonious succession of words having a pleasing sound

[Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/euphony)

Comment: Thank you very much, I am assuming that pragmatically, it is not common, to use a name instead of a pronoun. Thanks for your response Michael.

Comment: I'd say that it's more likely to be considered clumsy in normal unmarked conversation.

Comment: I tidied up your link (so you can see how it is done) and I added the actual pertinent meaning you were linking to. Feel free to undo if you wish.